# How do I turn a router into a wireless bridge

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge

I'm trying to get my HD satellite receiver connected to the internet - it has an Ethernet port on the back but my networking equipment is all upstairs.

I had the idea of connecting a spare wireless router to the box with an ethernet cable and getting that wireless router to talk to my "main" wireless router (the one with the ADSL connection) to supply internet access.  I believe this entails getting the router to work as a "wireless bridge", but I don't know how to do this.

Currently, the ADSL line is hooked up to a NETGEAR DG834G.  The other two "spare" wireless routers I have to act as the bridge are :-

- Huawei HG520b
- Netgear DGN2000
- BT Homehub

I'd prefer not to change the "main" router (cos I'm used to its web admin UI) - does anyone know a way I can achieve the connectivity I require with the equipment I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at 5-19 in the DGN2000 manual, "Repeater Mode":
ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/DGN2000_RM_04Aug08.pdf

Comment: Doesn't quite have the configuration I'm aiming for, but there's enough info there to hopefully cajole it into working the way I want - cheers.

Comment: bridged + AP mode is usually not supported on home grade wireless routers, and if you did pure bridging, you wouldn't be able to wirelessly connect any clients (laptops, etc.).

Comment: Hmm...looks like I'll have to do the networking over mains wiring trick then, as detailed at http://freesat.co.uk/index.php?page=iPlayer.UsingBBCiPlayer

Comment: Why not just setup the repeater?  You can plug the sat into one of the ethernet interfaces, the repeater mode should carry over all traffic from the "child" router to the "parent" router, regardless of wireless or wired connection.

Comment: Ok, that's what I had in mind, but was thrown by your note about "pure bridging".

I'm gonna accept your answer because its given me a lot of useful info and I don't want it to timeout while I work on this and then I can't accept it.

Thanks for your help